# Problem extracting everything between parentheses in Postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am writing a Postgresql query to return everything within parentheses inside a string. The string is "Account Suspended - Labeler has tumbling names with (dca-5:anna williams,dca-6:Anna Williams)." so the ideal output should be **dca-5:anna williams,dca-6:Anna Williams**.

I have tried the following syntax:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(an.comment,')',1),'(',-1) as new_comment
FROM public.akon_notes an
where an.comment like '%Account Suspended - Contributor has tumbling names with%'
```

But it returned the error message ***Amazon Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for integer: ")";***

Could somebody advise what I did wrong there?

Comment: your example and your code won't work together -- the like statement will not find that string -- is this as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `split_part()`.  Assuming you have no other parentheses in the string:

```
select split_part(replace(an.comment, ')', '('), '(', 2)
from (values ('"Account Suspended - Labeler has tumbling names with (dca-5:anna williams,dca-6:Anna Williams)."'::text)) an(comment);
```

`split_part()` splits the string based on a delimited.  Alas, you have two delimiters. so this replaces the `)` with `(`.  Because you want the first part *after* the `'('`, this is the second part of the string.  The above can be confused by the presence of other parens in the comment -- but it may be unclear how to handle that.

Another method uses `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(an.comment, '.*[(](.*)[)].*', '\1')
from (values ('"Account Suspended - Labeler has tumbling names with (dca-5:anna williams,dca-6:Anna Williams)."'::text)) an(comment);
```

This is more handy than `regexp_substr()` because you don't have deal with the leading and trailing parens.

This does what you want more directly.  The pattern matches the entire string (it could be `'^.*([)].*$' to be more explicit about that).  The first and last parens are escaped.  The part in the middle is identified as an element in the string.

The "replace" part of `regexp_replace()` replaces the entire string (because the pattern matches the entire string) with the first element matched (which is the part in parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex

```
substring(field,'\((.*)\)')
```

I didn't test you might need

```
substring(field,'.*\((.*)\).*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The below code used `Instr(..)` perhaps is general n should work in postgresql or can replace `instr()` with `strpos()`

```
    Select.... 
   SUBSTRING(an.comment, 
    INSTR(an.comment,'(')+1,
         INSTR(an.comment,')')-1)
       FROM TABLE like...
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not test this now, but I think that you can use regex for that:

```
SELECT substring(an.comment from '\((.*)\)') as new_comment
FROM public.akon_notes an
where an.comment like '%Account Suspended - Contributor has tumbling names with%'
```